# Write value from mysql into php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I execute a query which gives back several values. I need this values in a distinct style into an array. This is my code until now...

```
<?php
    $database_host = "localhost";
    $database_name = "tester";
    $database_user = "daniel";
    $database_pass = "admin";


    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tester;charset=utf8mb4', 'daniel', 'admin');

    $sql = "SELECT content, sum(amount) as Pkt FROM tabelle group by content";
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
       echo $row['content'].": ";
       echo $row['Pkt']."<br />";
    }
    ?>
```

I need the field 'content' in an array. Is it possible to write values into an array inside the existing foreach loop?

Thanks

Comment: Read please http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: `$var = array();` before the while. Then use `$var[] = $row['content'];` inside the while. You can check the array values by doing so after the while: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($var); echo '</pre>';`.

Comment: I just don't get the bigger picture...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible

```
$content = array();
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
   $content[] = $row['content'];
   echo $row['Pkt']."<br />";
}
```